# Get parameters from the intent used for onResume()

Tags: android, xamarin.android, onresume

I'm using a `LocalActivityManager` to have activities in different tabs, when I switch from a tab to another one, I start the `Activity` corresponding to the tab selected.
My problem is simple :

if I click on tab 1, I create `intent11` and the first time, the method `onCreate(Bundle emptyBundle)` of `Activity1` is called.
If I click on tab 2, I create `intent2` and the method `onCreate()` is called.
Then, when I click on tab1, I create `intent12` , the method `onCreate(Bundle emptyBundle)` is not called but `onResume()` is called (normal behavior).

I put special extras in the `intent11` and `intent12` to create `Activity1`, so I access it using `getIntent().getExtras()`.

My problem is : the second time I go to the tab1, the `intent12` is used to start the `Activity`, but the result of `getIntent()` is still `intent11`.
So I can't retreive the extras set in `intent12`, I can only retreive the extras set in `intent11`.

What am I doing wrong ? Should I avoid putting extras() in the intents ? Thank you.

Thank you.

PS : for the moment, I set a special flag to my intent to force to call onCreate(), but I'm sure it's not the good way of doing it.

Comment: It would be help if you also put the piece of your codes here.

Answer (score 6):

I believe what you are looking for is here:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent%28android.content.Intent%29

onNewIntent(Intent newIntent) allows you to override the previous intent that was used to create/resume the app with the newest intent.

Answer (score 2):

In Xamarin.Android / Monotouch I just added the following method to my Activity and it worked smoothly.

```
    protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        base.OnNewIntent(intent);
        Intent = intent;
    }
```

The principle should work fine also in Native Android.

Answer (score 1):

no you should be able to still put the extras but I'm wondering if the extras are getting 'overwritten' when you are creating the new intents so I suggest trying this:

Put your extras into the bundle for the first intent you create, then before creating the next intent set your bundle to whatever might be in the bundle already by doing

```
Bundle bundle = getResultExtras(false);
```

Then you can create your new intent then when you are ready to get your data out of the bundle you can do

```
Bundle bundle = getResultExtras(false);
```

again and then get your data like you normally would from the bundle, just make sure that the extras your put in Intent1 don't have the same key name as the extras you put in Intent2

hope that helps some.

if you need more specific help it might be useful to post your code.